# Can address space of VNET in different region overlap?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I just created a new VNET with address space 10.0.0.0/16 on West US, but got an warning on Azure portal says, The address space '10.0.0.0/16' overlaps with '10.0.0.0/16' in virtual network xxx. The VNET xxx was created before on another region.

Is it really an issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is only an issue if you connect the two VNETs together. That's why it's only a warning.

If you don't set up a VNET-to-VNET connection between the two, it is not a problem.