# The address space '10.0.0.0/16' overlaps with '10.0.0.0/16' in virtual network 'ABC'

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created two Virtual Networks in the same region but in a different resource group.
 But still, I'm getting a warning like `The address space '10.0.0.0/16' overlaps with '10.0.0.0/16' in virtual network 'XYZ-VNET'.`
 I referred to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41827643/6339597 but I still have some doubts because one of the resource groups is in production and another one is in a testing stage. Will it create any issues in the future?

How can I change address space of VNet? Because while deploying MongoDB sharding cluster it didn't ask me about address space for VNet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can address space of VNET in different region overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826429/can-address-space-of-vnet-in-different-region-overlap)

Comment: @juunas purpose behind the question is different that's why I asked.As you can see in my question I gave your answer link.

Comment: @juunas why downvote.? you can clearly see my question is about the same region not for the different region. you answer ddin't clear my doubts that's why I asked a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but I still have some doubts because one of the resource group is in
>   production and another one is in testing stage.will it create any
>   issue in future?

As juunas said, it is only a warn. If you don't connect the two VNets, it does not create any issue in future.  If you want to create a VNet-to-VNet VPN between the two VNet or peering the two VNet, it is not possible. Because they all require it:

**Do not overlap networks of each VNet.**

If possible, I suggest you could use different VNet address ranges. Such as like `10.1.0.0/16`.

Update from comment:

You could edit the template when you deploy it.

[image]

Note: If you want to change address ranges, please ensure you modify all of the ip address in the template.

Comment: Okay, @walter-MSFT. I don't need site-to-site VPN now but if I want it in future for any reason then I have to change address space.Right? Is there any way to change address space? if Yes, will it create any issues?

Comment: @TailorDevendra No, Azure does not support change address space after you create the VNet. So, you had better use different VNet address space.

Comment: I have deployed MongoDB-sharding-centos ARM but it didn't ask me any VNET configuration (Address space) so how can I give different address space for that virtual network?

Comment: Sorry, I am not at office now. I will test in my lab tommower. If you don't plan create VPN connection, you could use same address space, it does not affect any

Comment: it's okay @Walter-MSFT.  take your time.